# Multiline paste with relative columns alignment

Tags: cut-copy-paste, gvim, paste

When I have some text indented as follows (like `a` and `b` variables assignment):

```
if(condition)
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
end
```

and I want to paste `a` and `b` block somewhere outside of the `if` block, i.e just after it, vim adds the indentation starting from the second line of visual selection, resulting:

```
a = 1;
    b = 1;
```

Does exist such an option that don't expand the indentation (better said that maintains relative column alignment for each line) when text is pasted, without using a custom function ?

**EDIT:**
I mainly use gvim.

**EDIT2:**
I have already tried `set paste` and `set nopaste` without success.

Comment: Do you paste text from the OS clipboard or from a Vim register (`p` or `P`)?

Comment: I paste from Vim register using "+P. I paste the text into same file where I copy from.

Comment: @simo-zz Check register type: `echo getregtype('+')`. Also describe how did you copy.

Comment: @dedowsdi, I copy using `"+ygv` and paste using `"+P"`. The `getregtype('+')` ofcourse returns the yanked text. Don't you experience the same behaviour ?

Comment: @simo-zz It's `getregtype('+')`, not `getreg('+')`.  I think it's result it's result might be `v`. How did you complete visual selection before you call `gv`? And shouldn't it be `gv"+y` ?

Comment: @dedowsdi, sorry. Yes, the result of `getregtype('+')` is `v`. To select the text I just switch from normal mode to visual mode pressing `v`, then select the visual block with movement keys, so arrows, hjkl or using the mouse.

Comment: Try `V`. Also check `:h V`

Comment: I repeat the qiuestion:  don't you experience the same behaviour ?

Comment: @simo-zz Barely, most time i copy lines with `V`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to do that in Vim.

Here is a workaround:

First of all I have the following mapping in my `vimrc` (From [Vim Tips Wiki, Tip 759](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Selecting_your_pasted_text)):

```
nnoremap <expr> gp '`[' . strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1) . '`]'
```

With this you can visually select the text you have just pasted (or changed).

---

Note that `gp` is already used by Vim for

> Just like "p", but leave the cursor just after the new text.

So the mapping shadows the default functionality of `gp`. Maybe you want to change the mapping.

---

Then I do

1. Copy the text
2. Paste it with `p` (or `P`)
3. Reselect the pasted text with `gp` (the mapping above)
4. Reformat with `=` (or un-indent it with `<`)

Or short: <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>